# How to debug a child process in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm debugging a ***maven plugin goal (MOJO)*** in ***IntelliJ***.

With ***mvnDebug*** mode and ******remote*** debug configuration*** to connect on a port.

However, the execution is creating a separate child process, executing an Application inside the same project.

Please can anyone tell me how to attach to the newly created process? (To continue debugging in the same execution)

Comment: Why do you like to use `mvnDebug` which is used to debug Maven/Maven Plugin but not your own project. You can run debug mode from within IDEA IntelliJ directory ?

Comment: It is a maven plugin goal (MOJO), that I'm trying to debug. I'm executing it on a selected (random) project (with mvnDebug), and then I connect with remote configuration to the mvnDebug socket, which let me follow the execution of the plugins' source code in IntelliJ. The plugin is the one that creates a separate child process in terms of simple Java application (java.util.concurent.FutureTask that executes the given Runnable), on which I don't know how to connect.